# php $_POST can't get info from ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: php, iphone, post, asihttprequest

So in my implementation file, i have

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",jsonString];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSMutableData *postMutData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:postData];
ASIFormDataRequest *asi_request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[asi_request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(gotMyInfo:)];
[asi_request setPostBody:postMutData];
[asi_request setDelegate:self];
[asi_request startAsynchronous];
```

and in my php, i have

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$info = json_decode($json);
```

but i get an error: Undefined index 'json'
it's odd because i check the post with

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $input;
```

and it shows the json={....} properly.
I know i can just use the $input and decode the json from there but it seems "ugly".  Does anybody know why $_POST isn't working for this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not just posting the vanilla JSON as the body instead of using `json=` which is more like a query string parameter?

Comment: Wow i figured out the problem..
I used the setPostBody:postMutData which doesn't send form data to the php, so php won't recognize it with $_POST

I needed to do  [asi_request addPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"json"];

then it'll send the ?json={...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow i figured out the problem.. I used the setPostBody:postMutData which doesn't send form data to the php, so php won't recognize it with $_POST I needed to do

```
[asi_request addPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"json"];
```

then it'll send the ?json={...}

Answer (score 0):

check `post_max_size` in php.ini.

it's

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M
```

by default. try to change 8M to (for example) 20M